# Set index.jsp as default startup page for application Sencha Architect

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, extjs, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Architect below mentioned is the configuration that i am using

version: 3.0.4.1386
channel: 3.0.1-stable
platform: 1.3.0.803
cmd: 4.0.4.84
framework: Ext JS 4.2.x

I had placed index.jsp in my application folder and removed index.html, but when i do any changes to my ExtJS MVC application and then save and run it on apache tomcat server, it creates a new index.html file in my application folder and tries to run this newly created index.html.

I want to set index.jsp as my default startup page for the ExtJS application.

What am i missing here?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you changed it in web.xml as welcome-file?

Comment: @Braj I have the complete extjs application at the location specified "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\<name of app>" i dont see web.xml in application folder i.e. <name of app>, where will i find web.xml.

Comment: Go to WEB-INF/web.xml and Replace with `<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>`

Comment: @Braj Thanks for helping, i have not created a war file of my project so i dont have web.xml, my ExtJS web application folder exists in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\<name of app>" and i run it locally using localhost:8080/<name of app>

Comment: A web-application must have web.xml. I don't know what are doing? How are you deploying your application?

Comment: @Braj I have created a <app name> folder in apache-tomcat webapps folder using sencha architect and then i directly run application using the url localhost:8080/<app name> , as when we create application using sencha architect it doesn't create web.xml so i don't have web.xml in my ExtJS project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the `app.json` descriptor, adding the property:

**app.indexHtmlPath**

```
{
    "name": "ApplicationName",
    ...

    "app.indexHtmlPath": "index.jsp"

    ....
}
```

Details in application sencha folder: `.sencha/app/defaults.properties` file.
Form it:

```
# defaults to index.html, but may be overridden in app.json
app.indexHtmlPath=index.html
```

[Sencha Cmd docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command_app)

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I tried to do the entry of the above properties in the app.json, it did not work then i also tried to add it to app.json.meta file, still it did not work.

Comment: try to use `app.page.name` and `app.indexHtmlPath`(updated my answer). i'm not using architect but using sencha cmd tool it works.